# How many AMD exclusive instructions are there on zen 3 CPUs?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, instruction-set, amd-processor

How many instructions on zen 3 CPUs are exclusive to AMD?

I am aware of only 3: `mwaitx`, `monitorx`, and `clzero`

Also, the 3DNow! and lwp instruction sets were once AMD exclusive but they have since been removed.

Comment: I'm sure there are [**loads**](https://youtu.be/KrksBdWcZgQ). Not something you'll find in instruction manuals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the three instructions `MWAITX`, `MONITORX`, and `CLZERO` are supported on AMD Zen3 and no Intel processor (yet).

Zen3 also supports the [SSE4a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4) instruction set composed of 4 instructions (`EXTRQ`, `INSERTQ`, `MOVNTSD` and `MOVNTSS`) which is not supported by Intel.

It also supports the AMD-exclusive [SEV-SNP](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/x86/sme) instruction set (Secure Encrypted Virtualization - Secure Nested Paging) composed of 4 instructions (`PSMASH`, `PVALIDATE`, `RMPADJUST` and `RMPUPDATE`). It should also support older related instruction sets like SEV-ES (Secure Encrypted Virtualization - Encrypted State) composed of the instruction `VMGEXIT`. All of this is part of [AMD-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#AMD_virtualization_(AMD-V)) (all these abbreviations are a bit confusing). That being said, such instruction are typically available only on EPYC processors and not Ryzen ones. Moreover, AFAIK, Intel has similar instruction sets for this like for example [Total Memory Encryption](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/total-memory-encryption-security-paper.html). The alternative of AMD-V is [Intel VT-x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_(VT-x)).

Furthermore, the skinit instruction set (for security), which is (also) a part of AMD-V and composed of the 2 instructions `SKINIT` and `STGI`, is also AMD-specific. It appears to be available on some Zen processors (including Zen3) but it is not clear exactly which one (it at least targets AMD Ryzen PRO processors).

Like 3DNow!, the [FMA4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set) instruction set was exclusive to AMD. It was certainly supported on Zen1 though it was not officially the case (not present in any AMD Zen-related document nor provided by the CPUID instruction). Indeed, multiple users reported the instruction set was working correctly (see [[1]](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=838), [[2]](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen) and [[3]](https://www.techpowerup.com/248560/amd-zen-does-support-fma4-just-not-exposed)). Zen2 and Zen3 certainly do not support it at all (see the comment of @PeterCordes). Officially, the AMD's TBM, FMA4, XOP and LWP instruction sets (previously available on the Bulldozer architecture) are not supported on all Zen architectures (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOP_instruction_set)).

For more information, you can check the [AMD's manual (vol 3, rev 3.33)](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24594.pdf).

Comment: Last I heard (from Mysticial), FMA4 worked fine on Zen1 even though not reported by CPUID.  (There were rumours that it didn't always work perfectly, but those [all stemmed from one unsubstantiated report which was presumably user error](//stackoverflow.com/questions/47739456/why-is-this-code-using-vmulpd-to-write-registers-that-will-be-overwritten-by-vfm#comment82529280_47739755).)  And FMA4 faulted as an illegal instruction on Zen2 and later.  I can't find the original comment or chat message from Mysticial where he confirmed faulting, but IIRC that's why I edited that fact into my answer

Comment: According to wikichip AMD added technology called predictive store forwarding and an instruction to disable it (`PSFD`) Is this not AMD-exclusive? I understand you obviously put a lot of work into this answer, but it needs to be exhaustive to be correct

Comment: Based on the AMD manual, this is *not an instruction* but a CPUID bit. Besides, Intel mention it [here](https://www.amd.com/system/files/documents/security-analysis-predictive-store-forwarding.pdf) and it does not look like an exclusive feature either because "*PSFD is expected to be supported on all processors that support FSFP*" and "*FSFP [...] supported on certain Intel processors*".